# How to Reshape 2D to 3D Array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, lstm, reshape

I have an array that I would like to reshape for the purposes of training an LSTM in Python.
This is what my array looks like:

```
[[0,0,0,0,1]
[1,0,0,0,0]
[0,0,0,1,0]
[0,1,0,0,0]]
```

In this above example, there are 5 features. The other 4 features at that point are set to 0, and one feature is 1. I would like to reshape this using the (sample,timestep,feature) to create a 3D array.

I am using numpy, and naturally, the .reshape() function would work great.

Comment: Its already in a shape of (timestep, feature) isn't it? If you want to add a dimension here just do x[None,...].  If you want to stack a few of these do `np.array(x_list)`.

Comment: @sachinruk Yes, correct, it is in the timestamp,feature shape. You said I should add a dimension by doing x[None,...], I don't really understand that syntax. Can you clarify?

Comment: Putting `None` adds a dimension to make it (1, 4, 5) in your case. 1 is the sample size in this case. You would want a lot more samples for a LSTM.

Comment: It does, however, I wanted to inquire more about in which direction I should reshape the array... like whether it should be size (1,4,5), (4,1,5), or (4,5,1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to do with `numpy` using `.reshape` method:

```
A = np.array([[0,0,0,0,1], [1,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,1,0], [0,1,0,0,0]])
A = A.reshape(2, 2, 5)
print(A.shape)
```

So new shape is `(2, 2, 5)`. For your data you can just add a dummy dimension for a time step:

```
A = np.expan_dims(A, 1)
```

Comment: Hi, I would not like to create two samples at every single timestep. I want to maintain the current format, but make it three dimensional.

Comment: Thank you for updating your response. Upon doing expand_dims on my (2,5) array, I now get a (2,1,5) array. Should it be (2,1,5) or (2,5,1)?

Comment: It is all up to you, how you reshape the array. If you use `np.expand_dims(A, -1)`, you will get `(2, 5, 1)`. But for lstm, the input shape is `(batch_size, time_step, embedding_size)`. Your 0s and 1s are definitely embedding rather than time steps.

Comment: That clarifies things. The expand_dims definitely helped. +1 Thank you!